# How to properly display name, fullname, email from JSON record in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code which displays record from Monday API successfully.

I can get the JSON record via `{JSON.stringify(this.state.datax, null, 2)}` as per below

```
    [ { "items": [ { "id": "3150569213", "name": "Task 1", "column_values": [ { "id": "fullname", "value": null }, { "id": "status", "value": null }, { "id": "email", "value": null }, { "id": "phone_number", "value": null }, { "id": "address", "value": null }, { "id": "product", "value": null }, { "id": "quantity", "value": null }, { "id": "reward", "value": null } ] }, { "id": "3150569636", "name": "Recycle Products Share By ann balling", "column_values": [ { "id": "fullname", "value": "\"ann balling\"" }, { "id": "status", "value": "{\"index\":0}" }, { "id": "email", "value": "{\"text\":\"ann1@gmail.com\",\"email\":\"ann1@gmail.com\",\"changed_at\":\"2022-08-27T12:16:47.728Z\"}" }, { "id": "phone_number", "value": "{\"phone\":\"1234567890\",\"countryShortName\":null}" }, { "id": "address", "value": "{\"lat\":\"Texas,\",\"lng\":\"US\",\"address\":\"unknown\"}" }, { "id": "product", "value": "{\"text\":\"Paper,Bottles,Plastic Cans\"}" }, { "id": "quantity", "value": "\"200\"" }, { "id": "reward", "value": "\"Gift\"" } ] } ] } ]
```

How do I get values for **name, fullname, email**?

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import mondaySdk from 'monday-sdk-js';
import 'monday-ui-react-core/dist/main.css';

const monday = mondaySdk();
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      datax: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    monday
      .api(
        `query {boards (ids: 3150569212) {items(limit: 3 page: 1) {id name column_values {
            id
            value
          } }}}`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ datax: res.data.boards });
        //this.setState({datax: res.data.boards[0].items});
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Fullname</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.datax.map((i, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{i.name}</td>
                <td>{i.fullname}</td>

                <td>{i.email}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>

        {JSON.stringify(this.state.datax, null, 2)}

        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the first element in that case `items` and then map `column_values` since it is an array:

```
  {this.state.datax[0].items.map((i, index) => (
     <tr key={index}>
        <td>{i.name}</td>
        <td>{i.fullname}</td>
        <td>{i.column_values.map((val) => val.value)}</td>
      </tr>
  ))}
```

I have try it with the example you send and the output I get is like this, not very clean:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @S.Marx for getting back to me. I have tested your solution but it throwss error **TypeError: this.state.datax[0] is undefined**

Comment: are you setting yout state correctly? does `datax: []` have something? check it, it may the problem

Comment: Yes I can get it working now as per your screenshot above. please is there anyway to iterate to get values for fullname and email something like `{i.column_values.value}`  or `{i.column_values[0].value}`.  hoping to hear from you.  Thanks

Comment: What do you want to display? That data is a little bit confusing

Comment: name value is working fine, now i need to get **fullname** values eg Ann ball and **email** values eg. ann1@gmail.com etc

Comment: The problem is that the data you get if not well formed, in values like this one `value: '{"text":"ann1@gmail.com","email":"ann1@gmail.com","changed_at":"2022-08-27T12:16:47.728Z"}',}` those are string you need to get the data with values being `value: {}` not `value: "{}"`